# How to turn JQuery selection data into something a Django form can use

Tags: jquery, html, django, django-1.5

I've been reading up on Django, on the Django site, and the forms seem very straightforward and convenient.

However I can't figure out how to integrate the forms with my existing frontend which uses JQuery for part of its input.

On my site, there are a bunch of boxes that users can click on to select the types of food categories they are interested in. I've created [a simplified JSFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/fNsY2/2/)

When the user submits the form, I want to know what food categories he selected and process them as part of the request. 
Is there a mechanism in form that can allow me to do this?

---

**Code:**

HTML:

```
<div class="choice">
    Dairy
</div>
<div class="choice">
    Meat
</div>
<div class="choice">
    Snack
</div>
<div class="choice">
    Organic
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.choice {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    opacity: 0.35;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('.choice').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('isSelected') != "true"){
        $(this).attr('isSelected', 'true');
        $(this).css('opacity', '1');
    }
    else{
        $(this).attr('isSelected', '');
        $(this).css('opacity', '0.35');
    }
});
```

**A screenshot** of the simple example, for convenience. When user clicks a faded box, it's opacity turns to 1 (indicating it's selected) and when it's clicked again, it returns to faded view.

[image: simple JQuery selection]

Comment: What do your corresponding Django model and form look like (if they exist yet)? We'd need to know that to help

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about user interface where user can toggle some kind of input, then you are essentially talking about checkboxes.

If you had 4 checkboxes tied to corresponding divs you could just toggle the checkbox values and then post those hidden checkboxes as form for django to handle. Pretty simple stuff. Checkbox "name" attribute values must match a django form object (boolean)fields and you are pretty much set.

For example html:

```
<input name="dairy">
```

Django form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    dairy = forms.BooleanField()
```

If you do not want to use checkboxes in the background then you can post urlencoded associative array, where keys of associative array are django form objects (boolean)field names. Just remember that you do not need to post OFF values. You only need to post the values  of the selected elements. For example, lets say you have 4 options, Dairy, Meat, Snack and Organic with Dairy and Meat turned on. Then your post query should look like:

```
?dairy=on&meat=on
```

And that is pretty much it.

Comment: Thanks - the only problem is, that different users will have different forms, based on availability in their region. There could potentially be dozens of categories (and more can be added). I'd rather avoid hardcoding them all into one form (they won't all be shown, probably ever)

Comment: because you created a form with a dairy variable. If I do the same, there might be 100 variables, many of which are hardly used. Also, the categories are their own model, and there is a foreign key from region to category in the models

Comment: Well, you posed the question like "However I can't figure out how to integrate the forms with my existing frontend which uses JQuery for part of its input.". By that i understood you want to integrate it to forms. You do not have to. Django forms is one really easy way of picking up, validating and saving posted data in view. But you do not have to use forms, if you think that there are too many options that even creating dynamic forms has no point. You can pick up posteed variables from request.POST too. Your original question has too little information about what you are really trying to do.